# Value Error: setting an array element with a sequence ( array )

Tags: arrays, runge-kutta

Im getting this error while compiling this function :

```
def f(r,t):
    x,y,z = r[0], r[1], r[2]
    fx,fy,fz = sigma*(x-y), r*x-y - x*z, x*y-c*z
    return np.array([fx,fy,fz],float)
```

This is a function that i'm gonna use to apply the Runge-Kutta method. Im not sure what to do because, earlier, i used this functions and it worked just fine:

```
def f(r,t):
    x,y = r[0], r[1]
    fx,fy = alpha*x - beta*x*y, gama*x*y-sigma*y
    return np.array([fx,fy],float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i just saw that  im using "r" as a constant and also as a vector.